# Unable to locate package appmenu-gtk3

Tags: unity, package-management, appmenu

Yesterday I upgraded my version of Ubuntu. In stead of Gnome I now have the Unity environment. I'm not sure I like Unity better, so I'll give it a probation period to see if it's any good.

What I really do not like though, is the Global menu bar. After googling I found that I had to enter:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

If I do that I get the error message:

> E: Unable to locate package appmenu-gtk3

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and explain how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It already means that you don't have the `appmenu-gtk3` package installed in your computer.

If you are not convinced, try removing something that you obviously know doesn't exist.

For example,

```
sudo apt-get remove kinglear
```

would give the following error message:

> E: Unable to locate package kinglear

Comment: Okay thanks, but it should be installed, or otherwise I should not have that global status bar. And if I want to install it, it still cannot find that package. (If I do apt-get install appmenu-gtk3 I get the same error message)  So now my question is twofold: How do I uninstall the global menu bar, so that each window get's it's own menu. The other is: if ubuntu cannot find a package to install or uninstall how do I let it know where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the menu bar,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

Also you could try removing it by using Synaptic Package Manager.  If you need to install it

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering, but the problem is that if I enter that line in a shell I get an error message: "E: Unable to locate package appmenu-gtk3", so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mitch: the link from the logo does not "appear" in any browser (i.e. not clickable). Please fix when you get a chance...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it says there is no package as `appmenu-gtk3`, it is indeed the case. But you can disable global menu by following below procedure:

Go to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` and open the files `80appmenu-gtk3` and `80-appmenu` with administrative power.

command in terminal: `sudo gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80appmenu-gtk3` and comment out all the lines by putting a `#` mark before each line.

do this also for `80appmenu`, by opening with `sudo gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80appmenu`.

Logout and login again.